# Warning when adding Brownian force in COMSOL Multiphysics

Tags: fluid-dynamics, comsol

I want to add a *Brownian Force* to my COMSOL simulation. Unfortunately, I get the warning shown below and I do not understand how to get rid of it.

I am unsure what "second-order wall extrapolation" means. Moreover, I cannot find the "Wall accuracy order list in the physics interface Advanced Settings section" addressed in the warning message.

How do I correct this warning? How can I assign a Brownian force to a domain in general?

[image: Screenshot of my COMSOL simulation with the warning on the right]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem, click the "*Show More Options...*" button right below the Model Builder caption (the button has an eye as icon). An interface will pop up. In this interface, check the checkbox "*Advanced Physics Options*". Leave the Interface by clicking "*ok*". Then, click on "*Particle Tracing for Fluid Flow (fpt)*". Now, there should be an "*Advanced Settings*" drop down menu. In it, set "*Wall accuracy order*" to 1.

This gets rid of the warning.